# Unable to bind Style.Top to clicked checkbox's coordinates using Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

When I click a checkbox, I need to get its coordinates and use those as another div's top and left so that I can display the div right where the checkbox was clicked.
I have captured the checkbox click event as follows:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" [id]="item.Document.VENDOR_MAT" [checked]="isAddedInCompare(item.Document.VENDOR_MAT)" (change)="OnChangeUpdateProductCompareList(item.Document.VENDOR_MAT, $event)" (click)="onCompareClick($event)" /><label class="default-font" [attr.for]="item.Document.VENDOR_MAT" style="font-size:12px;margin-left:5px;">&nbsp;Compare</label>
```

Typescript:

```
 onCompareClick(e) {
    this.compareMessageTop = e.clientX;
    this.compareMessageLeft = e.clientY;
    }
```

This is setting the values.
But when I am trying to bind these values to div's style tag I see no change in its placement as per the coordinates of checkbox:

I am binding it as follows:

```
 <div class="compareOverflowMessage" style="margin:0 0 0 0;height:20%;width:20%;" [style.top]="compareMessageTop" [style.left]="compareMessageLeft">
```

I also tried adding

```
this.checkboxClicked.emit(this.compareMessageTop);
```

in the **onCompareClick(e)** to see if it emits the top and atleast binds that correctly but no luck.

Please help!!
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please create a plunkr of it showing what is happening and how do you bind style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" #cb1 (click)="calcPos(cb1)">
<input type="checkbox" [style.top.px]="cb2Top" [style.left.px]="cb2Left"
```

```
calcPos(element) {
  this.cb2Top = element.offsetTop + 20;
  this.cb2Left = element.offsetLeft + 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much! style.top.px & style.left.px worked for the binding. Though, I am setting Style for a Div. But when I use element.offsetTop , I get undefined as the value and if I try element.target.offsetTop & element.target.offsetLeft, I get 0. and it displays the div in top left corner instead of where the checkbox is. I tried : 
        this.compareMessageTop = e.clientX - e.target.offsetTop;
        this.compareMessageLeft = e.clientY - e.target.offsetLeft;
But this also doesnt give the correct position for the div. Please share if I missed something?

Comment: Hard to tell. Can you provide a Plunker that reproduces? I didn't think much about whether `offsetTop` is the correct property because it was not clear from your question what exactly the requirements are.

Comment: It worked.   I was setting   e.clientX for top instead of Left. and e.clientY for Left instead of top!